# How to pass an a single parameter in JSON body and why am I having an exception doing that?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here is the code I have:

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void create(@AuthenticationPrincipal AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser,
                   @RequestBody Integer restaurantId) {
    voteService.addVote(authenticatedUser.getUser(), restaurantId);
}
```

Here is the JSON body I pass to this method

```
{
        "restaurantId":1
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
    "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`);
 nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.
```

If I change value to String like this:

```
    @PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void create(@AuthenticationPrincipal AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser,
                   @RequestBody String restaurantId) {
    voteService.addVote(authenticatedUser.getUser(), Integer.parseInt(restaurantId));
}
```

I have this error:

```
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{
"restaurantId":1
}"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68) ~[na:na]
```

The question is how can I pass a single parameter in JSON body and why do I have these exceptions?

I do appreciate your answers a lot!

Comment: Do any of the answers resolve your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use @PathVariable or @RequestParam to accept the restautantid.

```
@PostMapping(value="/{restaurant_id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void create(@AuthenticationPrincipal AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser,
                   @PathVariable("restaurant_id") Integer restaurantId) {
    voteService.addVote(authenticatedUser.getUser(), Integer.parseInt(restaurantId));
}
```

Sample Request

```
curl -X POST  http://localhost/api/restaurants/2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method is accepting a String, but you’re JSON is providing a number.

Try wrapping your restaurantId in quotes in the JSON body, since your method is accepting it as a String. Or instead change your method to accept restaurantId as an Integer.